# manage data flow with SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm going to insert data to 3 tables.(According to my process.).But data must be entered into three tables.other wise i want to rollback transaction.
Eg:- if data inserted into 2 tables and didn't insert table 3, i want to delete entered values from the 2 tables.

What is the best way to do this.can i use trigger to do that? Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can try this :

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
 BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO Table1 values ()
INSERT INTO Table2 values ()
INSERT INTO Table3 values ()
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
raiserror('Custome Error Message ',16,20)
END CATCH
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

Using SET XACT_ABORT  ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back

In the catch block either you can raise a custom error or log it into a table

```
 Begin CATCH
 Insert into #LogError values (1,'Error while inserting a duplicate value')
 if @@TRANCOUNT >0
 rollback tran 
 END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transactions`

```
Commit tran -- if success
Rollback tran -- on error
```

Something like this

```
Create Proc YourSPName
AS

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO TableOne ( -- Columns)
VALUES  ( -- Values)

IF (@@ERROR <> 0) goto Truncater;

INSERT INTO TableTwo ( -- Columns)
VALUES  ( -- Values)

IF (@@ERROR <> 0) goto Truncater;

INSERT INTO TableThree ( -- Columns)
VALUES  ( -- Values)

IF (@@ERROR <> 0) goto Truncater;


Truncater:
if(@@ERROR<>0)
begin
    rollback tran
    return -1 -- error flag
end
else
    commit tran   

 GO
```

For more [Go here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions).

Comment: And since he's on SQL Server 2008, it would be easier to use the `TRY....CATCH` error handling, instead of constantly checking the `@@ERROR` variable.....